# How can I parse this json message appropriately to align work with my backend code?

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS to send messages and I'm testing locally for trial and error.

I'm having issues extracting the json key from the body of my mock message I copied below and I'm not sure why. When I run handler it runs the code below.

I am trying to determine the correct format for this. But I've also tested it in JSON validator and everything passed. It appears to be a problem with my code below when retrieving the actual keys (such as policy_id) I receive the error message **KeyError:** **'policy_type'.**

Does anyone know how I can extract keys from the mock json message or anything I can change in my mock json message for it to work? Any suggestions can also help.

```
def parse_alert_message(sqs_message):
 
    try:
        alert = json.loads(sqs_message)

        if alert['alertId'] == 'P-0':
            return {'error': "Error", 'data': alert['alertId']}

        parsed_alert = {
            'policy_type'        : alert['policyType'],
            'policy_Id'          : alert['policyId'],
            'account' : {
                'name'           : alert['accountName'],
                'account_id'     : alert['accountId']
            },
            'region'             : alert['resourceRegionId'],      
            'metadata'           : alert['resource'],
            'severity'           : alert['severity']
        }

    except Exception as e:
        return {'error': str(e), 'data': None}    


def handler():

    print(event['Records'])
```

Here is the the test JSON message

```
      "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "059f36b4-87a3-44ab-83d2-661975830a7d",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBwJnKyrHigUMZj6rYigCgxlaS3SLy0a...",
            "body": {"severity":"CRITICAL","alertTs": "timestamp", "data":"P-123", "resource":"resource","resourceId":"riskybucket4testing", "policyType": "config", "policyName": "PolicyNameTest", "policyId": "4daa435b-fa46-457a-9359-6a4b4a43a442", "alertRuleName":"JTB-SQS Alerts","alertRemediationImpact":"null","accountName":"jtb75-002-pan","hasFinding":"false","resourceRegionId":"us-east-1","alertRemediationCli":"null","source":"Prisma Cloud","cloudType":"aws", "accountId": "12345678", "alertId":"P-1000"},
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1545082649183",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIENQZJOLO23YVJ4VO",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1545082649185"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:my-queue",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code and example you show you'll need to do something more like:

```
parsed_alert = {
    'policy_type'        : alert['Records'][0]['body']['policyType'],
    ...
}
```

or, to eliminate the duplicate code with multiple fields:

```
body = alert['Records'][0]['body']

parsed_alert = {
    'policy_type'        : body['policyType'],
    ...
}
```

These fields are nested inside of the message and so you need the full "path".

Comment: Thanks, does this also apply to the SQS format listed here ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Comment: It looks like it but the key is that with nested classes you'll need to give the path.